# How can I specify the number of columns in a collection view?

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

This could also be the number of cells per row, which ever is easier.

My code for the collection view is this:

```
let reuseIdentifier = "cell"

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    cell.myLabel.text = String(self.items[indexPath.item])

    return cell
}
```

with this in the MyCollectionViewCell:

```
class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
}
```

I want the number of cells per row (or columns) to be a third of `items.count` and there to be 3 rows. I have tried playing with the number of sections and items per section, as well as cell width. If cell width could work that would be best so it would work for all devices.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.size.width/score1.count)
}
```

Comment: Use self.view.frame.size.width / numberOfcellsperrow. This will give you each cell's width based on the screen size. And now use sizeforitematindexpath method to pass this width.

Comment: Where in the code do I implement this?

Comment: func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.size.width/numberofcellsperrow - spacingbetweencell, height: heightofcell spacingbetweencell)
  }

Comment: I tried what I put in the normal section. It doesn't work. It doesn't like the calling of width.

Comment: Unable to understand what you are saying.. Please provide detail description what you want to acheive